# Vulnerability in RabbitMQ : disable cleartext authentication mechanisms in the amqp configuration

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

How to disable cleartext authentication mechanisms in the amqp configuration ?

Answer (score 9):

without going into TLS details, you must:

- Disable normal authentication, by stop using [non-TLS port 5672](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#ports) by leaving config entry empty `{tcp_listeners, []}`
- Enable TLS by adding config entry `{ssl_listeners, [5671]}`
- Further configure [TLS support details on server](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html), like

  ```
    {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"/path/to/ca_certificate_bundle.pem"},
                   {certfile,"/path/to/server_certificate.pem"},
                   {keyfile,"/path/to/server_key.pem"},
                   {depth, 2},
                   {verify,verify_peer},
                   {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}]}
  ```
- Make sure your client API supports TLS for peer verification (as well as securing the traffic). Here you have the [.NET](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#dotnet-client) and [Java](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#java-client) client APIs details.

**Notes:**

- Peer verification and passwords (for certificates) are supported and optional. You can have a password-less certificate and enable or disable peer verification.
- Some clients have specific requirements about certificates types and content